# Mysql getting ready to do 2014 monthly partitions

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning, information-schema

I need to get the list of Databases and Tables of all tables that have not been partitioned for 2014.
I was thinking querying the `information_schema`.`PARTITIONS` that meet the following conditions:

```
PARTITION_NAME IS NOT NULL
PARTITION_NAME='p201312'
AND PARTITION_NAME !='p201401'
```

How could I query this. I've tried:

```
select DISTINCT * FROM(select `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME` from `information_schema`.`PARTITIONS` where PARTITION_NAME IS NOT NULL AND PARTITION_NAME='p201312' AND PARTITION_NAME!='p201401') as a;
```

But does not work. Please help.

*** UPDATE ****

I was able to put together a query to get what I needed:

> SELECT a.`TABLE_SCHEMA`, a.`TABLE_NAME` FROM (select `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME` from `information_schema`.`PARTITIONS` where PARTITION_NAME='p201312') as a
>   LEFT JOIN (select `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME` from `information_schema`.`PARTITIONS` where PARTITION_NAME='p201401') as b
>   ON a.`TABLE_NAME` = b.`TABLE_NAME` WHERE b.`TABLE_NAME` IS null;

Is there a way to make this query a little more elegant??

Comment: no errors but still shows tables where PARTITION_NAME is p201401

Comment: and I just need tables that are partitioned only until 2013 (p201312)

Comment: What is the point of using the subquery?

Comment: I need to query all tables that have partition like p201312 but not like p201401. So I was trying to select the `TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TABLE_NAME` from information_schema

Comment: But why not just say `select distinct table_schema, table_name from information_schema.partitions where ...` rather than `select distinct * from (subquery)`?

Comment: My objective is to find all the tables that had not been monthly partitioned for 2014.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    table_schema, 
    table_name 
from 
    information_schema.tables t
where 
    not exists (
        select 
            null 
        from 
            information_schema.partitions p 
        where 
            p.table_schema = t.table_schema and 
            p.table_name = t.table_name and 
            p.partition_name like 'p2014%'
        )
```